# PowerPivot use max date for MTD if no record exists

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I want to calculate the MTD sales of products, however some products aren't always sold everyday. Using the time intelligence DAX functions `TOTALMTD` ignores products if there are no sales for the selected date. e.g. if I have product A and B

Data:

```
Product InvoiceDate Sales
A   2016/12/01  1
B   2016/12/01  2
B   2016/12/02  3
```

What I want to show with MTD calc:

```
Product InvoiceDate 
A   2016/12/02  1
B   2016/12/02  5
```

What I currently get:

```
Product InvoiceDate 
B   2016/12/02  5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure how or **if** you can achieve this via a Pivot table, I was able to do this using a *linked DAX query*. To learn more about how you can run a linked DAX query, [look here](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/linkback-tables-in-powerpivot-for-excel-2013/).

Before my formula, I created a calendar table in PowerPivot (Design Tab -> Date Table). You don't need to do this, but in order to have a fool-proof solution, you probably should. Create a calendar table on the side, then join it to your main table using the Date column.

Here's my DAX:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE(CROSSJOIN(VALUES(Table[Product]),VALUES(Calendar[Date])),[Product],[Date]
,"Sales",SUM(Table[Sales])
,"MTD sales",TOTALMTD(SUM(Table[Sales]),Calendar[Date])
)
```

Using this query I was able to achieve the following results:

[image]

I think that's exactly what you were looking for. The solution may be a bit tricky for a beginner, so let me know if I can clarify anything for you.